# Retrofit 2 Android objetos

Tags: android, json

Não consigo de jeito nenhum pegar os valores.

O valor recebido pelo JSON são esses:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "valores": {
        "galo": {
            "nome": "galinho",
            "valor": 300,
            "ultima_consulta": 1386349203,
            "fonte": "galo.com.br"
        }
    }
}
```

Ja tentei de tudo, nada da certo.

```
RespostaServidor respostaServidor = response.body();

Valores valores = respostaServidor.getValores();
galo = valores.getGalo();
```

Na classe `respostaServidor`, ele pega o `status` certo, e o objeto, mas depois passa o valor nulo para o galo.

Não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: Galo é um objeto dentro do json, um "filho".
Por exemplo:
{
   "pedido": 1,
    "itens": {
                   "codItem": 1
                }
}

jsonObject objetoPedido = json.getObject("pedido");
....
e depois ler os itens assim: 
objetoPedido.getObject("itens");

Comment: Poste a classe Valores.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.
Vamos supor que você tenha feito algo assim:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://exemplo.com")
            .build();
```

Também utilizo retrofit. E para fazer o parse do *json* para objetos, estou utilizando *GsonConverterFactory*. Somente acrescentando nas dependências do *gradle*:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Então construindo o retrofit desta forma:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://exemplo.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Se está falando isso no seu código, talvez seja esse o problema.

Seria interessante detalhar um pouco mais sobre como você está trabalhando com o retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://portaljuventude.includetecnologia.com.br/api/";

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder
        =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()));

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```